# Running node.js proccess step by step

Tags: node.js, synchronization

I was a PHP developer, I'm trying to write code using node.js for praticing. M am confuse about node.js when I execute my program, line of code jump to next line.

This is the part of my code:

```
//article.js    
var article_model    = require('../models/article_model');
var comment_model    = require('../models/comment_model');

var list_article,list_comment;

app.set('views','./views/article/');
app.set('view engine','ejs'); 

app.get('/list_article',csrfProtection,function(req,res){

 master_model.get_article(req,xparams,function(status,result,total_data){  
     list_article  = result.data;
    });
 console.log(list_article);

 master_model.get_comment(req,xparams,function(status,result,total_data){  
     list_comment  = result.data;
    });
console.log(list_comment);

var params = {  
               title         : "Article List",
               data_article       : list_article,

           };
           res.render('content.ejs',params);
});
```

and then

```
//master_model.js
exports.get_article = function (req,hash, fn) {


     var auths = {
      user : api_server["auth_username"],
      pass : api_server["auth_password"],
    }


    request.get({url:"http://myapi.com/article/latest", auth:auths  } , function(err,httpResponse,body) {  
      if (!err && httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        var temp  = JSON.parse(body);

          if (temp.status == 1){
            result_data = {status:1, message : temp.message ,data : temp.data};
            return fn(true,result_data,1);

          }else if(temp.status == 0){
            result_data ={ status:0, message : temp.message};
            return fn(false,result_data,0);
          }

      }else{
        result_data ={ status:0, message : "error, please try again"};
        return fn(false,result_data,0); //something problem to API
      }

    })


};

exports.get_comment = function (req,hash, fn) {


     var auths = {
      user : api_server["auth_username"],
      pass : api_server["auth_password"],
    }


    request.get({url:"http://myapi.com/comment/latest", auth:auths  } , function(err,httpResponse,body) {  
      if (!err && httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        var temp  = JSON.parse(body);

          if (temp.status == 1){
            result_data = {status:1, message : temp.message ,data : temp.data};
            return fn(true,result_data,1);

          }else if(temp.status == 0){
            result_data ={ status:0, message : temp.message};
            return fn(false,result_data,0);
          }

      }else{
        result_data ={ status:0, message : "error, please try again"};
        return fn(false,result_data,0); //something problem to API
      }

    })


};
```

when i run my code, and open browser, output data is blank, when i refresh again my browser show ouput my data (artcile list, and commment list)

and i look my console if first run

```
output : {
     id : 1
     title : title 1..
     ...
     ..
}
undefined
```

If i refresh my browser again, all output complete to show (not show undefined)

My question:
How to make my code run the process step by step until the process end and deliver to views?

Any problem with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Code doesn't jump. Javascript is linear, except where an event triggers a callback (which is better described as async than non-linear). When the browser makes a request on a route, the function that handles the request gets called, and all lines will be called in order, inside the callback.

Comment: @SamMorrowDrums thanks for answer. so how my code sync on the line.?

Comment: I don't know where to start with the above - you have too much going on. You should probably start by breaking this down into smaller programs. Do a basic hello world... learn how callbacks work, and how you can manage state, without using authentication, ejs and multiple modules... This is too complex to make suggestions. `app.set('views','./views/article/');` - that looks like you are using the module express, however you then seem to be using the standard HTTP server. I think you have jumped in too deep. If you can isolate a few features, it shouldn't take you long to get back to this point

Answer (score 0):

To address your initial question properly, you can actually go step by step, using breakpoints. In the latest node 7 and now 6 you can use Chrome Dev Tools to debug a node application. You need to set some breakpoints and watch variables to help you understand:

- execution order
- the precise values of variables at key moments

I still think breaking the big program into smaller programmes would be helpful and reduce surprises, but learning to debug properly is also really useful!

You just run the program with `node --inspect index.js`, and then a link will be displayed on the console that you load up in Google Chrome Browser.

There is a more [thorough guide](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27#.esg0tetrv), which might help.

The [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js) is also worth a read.